# Measuring background radiation

Tags: experimental-physics, nuclear-physics, water, radiation

We tried to measure background radiation using a geiger counter for a experiment at school. The meter showed  $0.12$-$0.21$ microSv/h during the day averaging at about $0.14$ mcSv/h.

As we tried to see ways how to shield incoming radiotion nothing seemed to work. Taking a cue from nuclear power plant we put the meter into a watertigt glasscontainer and sank it in the gym pool so that the container had a good three feet of water all around. The measurement did not budge at all. We tried all settings fast/slow/auto. The geiger meter should be okay as it had recently been calibrated.

Can someone explain.

Comment: Props to you for taking the extra step of dropping the Geiger counter in the pool! Right idea, just not enough material. By the way, nuclear power plants use water as coolant, not to absorb radiation (although the water does still absorb some).

Comment: The water in the nuclear power plants has boron in it that absorb neutrons if I recall correctly ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you are not living close to a uranium mine or other natural sources of radioactivity the main radioactivity  that your geiger counter measures outside is  [cosmic radiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_radiation).   At sea level this is composed mainly  by muons , which are weakly interacting and will not be stopped by a meter of water. This is also true for cosmic origin neutrons . ( neutrons from reactors are of lower energy).

Electrons and gammas  will be stopped but possibly your counter is not good for measuring electrons which can be stopped by a metal cover.

You could try measuring in a second basement, low energy muons will be absorbed by the ground above. On the other hand there is natural radioactivity in the ground and the cement of the basement.  Still you might see a controllable difference. Have a look at this list of [natural radiation.](http://www.iaea.org/Publications/Booklets/RadPeopleEnv/pdf/chapter_7.pdf)

Comment: To emphasize Anna's point about the muons, in the neutrino and dark matter communities it is usual to go "deep" underground to reduce the cosmic muon rate. In those communities rock equivalent to 300 meters of water (Double Chooz Far) is a shallow detector, 1800 meters water equivalent (MWE) (KamLAND) is a medium depth detector. Really deep detector are 3000 MWE or deeper.

Answer (score 0):

Thans for all answers and links.

If cosmic radiation is about 0.03 mcSv/h we should still see a drop.
There is no power plant in the area. 
The pool was an indoor pool and it is in the basement which has a solid concrete ceiling.

How would I set this experiment to show that the counter goes down preferably to zero.

Comment: You can only set your counter to zero by raising the level of the energy detected. Otherwise there is always background radiation to which a geiger counter will respond. Muons go through concrete with little problem. You can measure outside in the open air, and then go down the basement and see the difference. If your counter is working low momentum muons will be absorbed  and there will be a difference. There will be no difference between next to the pool and in the water at a meter depth because muons are not affected by a meter of water.

Comment: Other than changing the level of energy in the meter is there any way or material than can shield the meter from muons?

Comment: If you read dmckee's comment where he gives numbers, no it is not really possible. There are something like one muon per cm square per second falling on us all the time. They are relatively harmless and some think that a background radiation is necessary for the health of our cells. If you read the link about natural radiation you will see that there is always some. Most elements of the things around us have some radioactive isotopes in addition to the ubiquitous muons. You can measure differences in levels though.

Comment: OK. Thanks. What could I use to demonstrate shielding using lead or something else.

Comment: .. preferably a household item that has radiation which shows up in the geiger counter and that can be shielded easily with a bucket of water or a plate of lead.

On the subject of muons: they are listed as directly ionizing with sufficent kinetic energy. Why are they not harmfull when other similar types are? Their half life is short but if they are continuous isn't that harmful as well?

Comment: They are part of the "natural radiation" ( look at the link) to which biological organisms have adjusted during their evolution. It is excess over the background  radiation that is harmful.  Muons only ionize, alpha and and neutrons because they can interact strongly can do much more damage .

Comment: Old enough lantern mantles contain enough thorium to set the meter to ticking, and [original Fiestaware](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiesta_(dinnerware)#Radioactive_Glazes)(plates and stuff) used uranium based glazes which do a fine job as example source. I have a bright orange salt-shaker in that stuff that registers several time background at 10 cm.